# Sublime Cofee-Script Plugin Error: EACCES, permission denied '/.DocumentRevisions-V100'

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, sublimetext2

I installed coffee-script, and it's working fine through terminal.
I cloned and installed the coffee-script plugin through sublime here:
https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle

I followed the readme instructions:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/
git clone git://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle CoffeeScript
```

Now, when I press command B in sublime to activate the conversion... I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:134
      throw err;
            ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/.DocumentRevisions-V100'
  at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:654:18)
  at compilePath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-        script/command.js:128:20)
  at compilePath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:140:23)
  at Object.exports.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:95:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee:7:41)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
  at startup (node.js:119:16)
  at node.js:906:3

[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 8]
```

My guess, is that sublime does not have administrative access.  I know if I'm giving myself access, I'll work through 'sudo', but how do I give sublime access in this case?

Thanks guys!

-Will

Comment: you don't need to give anything superuser access, this should work out of the box as-is. Have you upgraded your node `coffee-script` bundle lately? You might want to try bringing it up to date.

Comment: I'd also suggest trying some other plugins to see if it's node's fault or the plugin's. Install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net) then get the [`CoffeeScript`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CoffeeScript) and [`Better CoffeeScript`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Better%20CoffeeScript) packages, and see how they work. There are differences in their build systems, so one might work better for you than another.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it's the permission problem.

```
sudo chown -R user3546595 coffee-script-tmbundle
```